# Keycloak - Same user in many repositories stops the User providers cascade validations

Tags: java, keycloak

I have a Keycloak server configured with two User Storage Providers: one for querying a LDAP server (using the SPI already implemented in Keycloak) and another which looks into a client's DB with users info (this is a custom Keycloak's extension programmed in Java).

Both of them works fine: I ask Keycloak to validate credentials of one user registered in LDAP and it works as expected for the pair user/password. The same happens when the user is registered in the client's DB.

The problem arise when the user is defined (with different passwords) in both the LDAP and the client's DB: Keycloak looks for the user name in one of them (the DB for example) and founds it. Then try to validate the password and fails giving Keycloak the result '401 Unauthorized' and not trying to validate the password on the LDAP.

Is there a way to make Keycloak to search the user in every User Storage Provider althought any of them fails to validate the user?

Comment: Seems that you have to incapsulate both of LDAP and your custom provider into single composite provider that should implement your desired user resolution logic.

Comment: Thanks @solveMe That is my last option. I would like to use separate User Storage Providers for different sources.